# Omited parameters in a url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In the book: 'The Django's book 2.0' the author talk about using 'catchers' in the url. According to him, you can omit some parameter in the url and define it in the `views.py` in order to prevent an error 404:

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hours/(?P<hour>\d+)/$', views.date_in),
```

`views.py`

```
def date_in(request, hour='02'): #Default argument defined here
    hour=int(hour)
    #some extra code
```

This doesn't work for me. I still get the error 404 because the argument after hours doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You did not omit the `hour` argument in your `urls.py`. Try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hours/(?P<hour>\d+)/$', views.date_in),
    url(r'^hours/$', views.date_in),
```

This will create two routes for the same view. One that accepts a `hour` argument, and one that does not. The one without the `hour` argument will use the default value (`'02'`).

Comment: So i can't define hour='02' in order to prevent the error 404 in a single url?

Comment: No, you can't have default arguments in your url patterns.